# Get registered user's country or IP

Tags: users

i am very beginner to WP, so excuse me

Q1: does WP be default stores user's country/IP address ?
Q2: how can i know the country/city or IP of each registered user?

it will be nice if this can be shown in **/wp-admin/users.php** page list, or even if its a DB query that i can run and see the results. I checked many articles and plugins, most of them gives you results for the the visitors nothing for the registered users

Your help is highly appreciated. thnx

Answer (score 1):

You can't know the country / IP / etc. of any user:

- the admin could create any number of users, and before each of those users log in, there is no way for WP to know their IP
- even after an user logs in, you can't be sure he/she would log in from the same IP or even city, country, etc. each time

What you could see is the last IP that an user used to log in. A good plugin for that (and lots of other useful security functions) would be [WordFence](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wordfence/). In the dashboard, you can see the last logins from your users, with username, IP and date:
[image: WordFence Dashboard Login Attempts]

Comment: You're welcome! If my reply answers your question you should accept it.